# Why implicit free's declaration is taken vararg parameter in llvm

Tags: clang, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

Taken the following code

```
int main() {
  int* a = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
  free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

If compile it to llvm IR by `clang -S -emit-llvm -O0 -g`, free's declaration is:

```
declare i32 @free(...) #2
```

However, if I add `#include <stdlib.h>`, free's declaration is:

```
declare void @free(i8*) #2
```

By adding include, the declaration is obviously taken from the header file, but why implicit free's declaration is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C (when permitted by the operative C Standard) the implied type of a function `foo` that is called without a prior
prototype or definition is `int foo()`, which in C means *function taking unspecified arguments, returning int*.
Implicit declaration of functions is illegal as of C99 and always illegal in C++.

If you compiled exactly that code with exactly those options you will have seen
warnings for the implicit declarations of `malloc` and `free`, although they
do not make it clear what the implied types are. If you compiled with with clang++ instead of clang you would have seen two *errors*.